# Django: specify file paths in a JavaScript file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have the following directory structure which follows Django's standard:

```
/my_site
    /my_site
    /my_app
        /static
            /my_app
                /js
                    a.js
                    b.js
                    c.js
                    d.js
```

I have no problem specifying the static path in the html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'my_app/js/a.js' %}"></script>
```

However, there are some statements in file `a.js` as follows:

```
var WORKER_PATH = 'b.js';
var encoderWorker = new Worker('c.js');
importScripts('d.js');
```

I was not able to set the paths for `b.js`, `c.js`, and `d.js` correctly (but they all locate in the same directory!). How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another `<script>` tag in your html:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var js_b = "{% static 'my_app/js/b.js' %}";
    var js_c = "{% static 'my_app/js/c.js' %}";
    var js_d = "{% static 'my_app/js/d.js' %}";
</script>
```

After that, you can use variable `js_b`, `js_c`, and `js_d` in your `a.js` JavaScript file, as they'll be strings of static paths of `b.js`, `c.js`, and `d.js`.

You can also get those variables from your view and return them with your RequestContext:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

# in your view function
js_b = static('my_app/js/b.js')
js_c = static('my_app/js/c.js')
js_d = static('my_app/js/d.js')
context = {'js_b': js_b, 'js_c': js_c, 'js_d': js_d}
return render_to_response('your_template.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```